# Perl printf in PHP

Tags: php, perl

I need to rewrite this from perl to php

```
printf(DATA "%-*s% *d\n", $max_length, $key, $length_number+1, $hash{$key});
```

Can someone help me? Thank You

Comment: You clearly did no research on your own.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I found everywhere something like printf( "%-10s", "Hello" ); but I need replace that number by variable and asterisk dont work.

Comment: Finally I found it. Its printf("%-{$variable}s", "Hello");

Answer (score 1):

PHP has printf:
https://www.php.net/printf

What's more, PHP's variable interpolation is very similar to Perl's, so this should be a very straight-forward mapping.